# Ubuntu 20.04 does not recognize my password. What to do?

Tags: boot, grub2, password

Just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on PC machine after failed Windows 11 --> 10 rollback attempt (it failed too).  Now I recall the user name I chose but I don't recall the password (or rather the password that I chose doesn't work).  I guess I need to change the password in boot (Ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64).

Any suggestions anyone? I have tried to call up GRUB with Shift repeatedly pressed during boot, and grub does not come up, and there are no responses to commands.

Grub only comes up when ESC pressed, not with left-shift.  Holding both left-shift + ESC does nothing.

Grub comes up on screen with top line GNU GRUB version 2.04. Next line below top "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.  For first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions."
grub>

Pressing TAB at this point gives a large number of possible commands spread out across screen.  Among possibilities I tried are password, legacy_check_password, others.  grub responds with:

```
Secure Boot forbids loading module from (hd0.gpt2)/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/password.mod.
```

Nothing like described in all the kind answers I have received.

Comment: You don't issue commands to GRUB. You use Recovery Mode. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Answer (score 0):

Got it, new password installed and successfully entered Ubuntu.  Thanks to Jorge Castro's hints.  There are two lessons to learn:

1. on a modern EIFI machine, things happen very fast.  Be prepared to press the ESC key (or left-shift + ESC on some machines) after entering the motherboard password.  Do not press it but once, and do not hold more than 1-2 seconds.  This will put you in grub menu, and not >grub.
2. the correct spelling for password in the grub selection is 'passwd'.

Thanks to all for helpful answers!